# Purpose of property with empty set get

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop, properties

Can someone tell me, what is the porpose of using a public property for a private class member but not implementing anything in the set and get part? I know that it could be just for examples and that later on you can implement something but I don't know if there is any meaning using it like that

Comment: That could be an auto-implemented property.  Depends on what you mean by empty and whether it is VB or C#

Comment: Are you referring to auto properties? i.e., public int Foo { get; set;}

Comment: @MichalHainc I do not believe it is a duplicate of that question. Read his question carefully and see my answer.

Comment: @MichalHainc i appreciate that you want to clear all duplicate questions, but i was not satisfied whit the answers that i found, sorry for not reading everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to assume you know there is a private field generated by the C# compiler as the field backing up this property. It is syntactic sugar. I am also going to assume you know this is an auto-implemented property. So what is the point of a property if it public with no logic in the `get` or `set`. In other words, any class can access it and set its value. So why choose this property over a public field?

Purpose of it is:

1. Today the `get` and `set` is empty but it may need code in the future. To avoid breaking a contract in the future, you use an empty `get` and `set`.
2. Most .NET databinding can be done against properties but not fields. So although it is empty, it still serves a far greater purpose.
3. The `get` and `set` can have access modifiers. For example, you can say `set` is private but `get` is public.
4. A field cannot be used in interfaces but properties can.

Answer (score 3):

This is an "auto-implemented" property in C#.  In effect, the property acts as a full property, i.e.:

This:

```
public int Number { get; set; }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
private int _number;

public int Number
{
    get
    {
        return this._number;
    }
    set
    {
        this._number = value;
    }
}
```

This prevents you from having to type out the full property declaration.  This is useful when you don't have any additional logic in the getter and/or setter.

If you're creating simple data mapping and transfer classes, auto-implementing properties can make the class definition far more concise.

Answer (score 1):

When you see

```
public int Count { get; set; }
```

as a member of a class, that is *not* nothing. You're just deferring to the default implementation of auto-properties. It's roughly,

```
private int _count; 

public int get__Count() 
{
    return _count;
}

public void set__Count(int value) 
{
    _count = value;
}
```

You just have syntactic sugar in C# to use these methods roughly like a field, i.e.

```
instanceOfObject.Count = 42; // Not a field access, but behind the scenes a method call.
```

Comment: @MichalHainc That's a fair opinion. If you think my answer is not useful or doesn't not contribute to Stack Overflow, you're welcome to down vote it.